# How to tell R Markdown that a current chunk returns a Latex Code

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I'm new to R Markdown and got a problem right now. I want to do a Table one with mean and sd for some variables and for that pursue I'm using compareGroups and createTable. There is also a function, called export2latex, which converts the table into LaTex code but unfortunately I don't know how to tell R Markdown that the current chunk is already Latex and it should convert it.

I've tried it with **results = 'tex'** in the chunk options but without success. Right now it just displays the latex code in my pdf like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJgus.png). Here is the image of my [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7ptT.png).

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**
As mentioned, results="asis" helped out, so thank you. But there occurs a second problem after doing that. It seems like you need to use such a latex generated code as an inline expression, because knitr can't handle the latex math environment. So I did it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bcz6V.png). Now LaTex is able to compile the file but now there appears two dollar signs in my pdf.

Can someone tell me how to get rid of it?

Comment: Hi trqkiz. Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not post images of code or data here. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [minimale reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).That way you can help others to help you!

Comment: `results="tex"` is a Sweave option.  RMarkdown uses knitr, so you want `results="asis"`.